# Weird behavior with Regex matching

Tags: javascript, regex

[Here is a Codepen version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoZyYW).

My goal is to iterate over the elements of an array, search for a regex matching `~@`something`@~`, remove those "bookends" identifying the match, then `.join()` the array. In the following example, the result should look like `a/b/c`.

However instead, I get the result `a/~@b@~/c`. To make things even more confusing, when I reverse the order of the array elements, the problem result changes from the `~@b@~` to the `~@c@~`. And, finally, to make things downright weird, the problem seems to resolve itself by adding a simple `test` method which, itself, always returns a value of `false`. See comments for those in code. And see for yourself.

What is causing this strange behavior? And what is the correct way to iterate over these elements and do the substitution I describe?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = ["a", "~@b@~", "~@c@~"]
  var re = /~@(.*?)@~/g;
  var i = a.length;
  //  Uncomment below line to see the problem change from ~@b@~ to ~@c@~
  //a.reverse();
  while (i--) {
    console.log('i', i, 'str', a[i]);
    var match = re.exec(a[i]);
    console.log('match', match);
    // Uncomment the below line to see it work properly.
    //console.log('test', re.test(a[i]));
    if (match && match[0] && match[1]) {
      a[i] = a[i].replace(match[0], match[1]);
      console.log('a[i]', a[i]);
    }
  }
  var res = a.join('/');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>
  My goal is to print the string: <code>a/b/c</code>. See weird <i>uncomment</i> fix in JS.
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Yes: *string interpolation*. See below comment to accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the behavior is that your regex has the global flag (`g`) but you're only executing it once; that means its `lastIndex` is set and the next time you run it, it tries to start from where it left off.

Either remove the `g` flag, or add

```
re.lastIndex = -1;
```

...as the first line in the `while` loop:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = ["a", "~@b@~", "~@c@~"]
  var re = /~@(.*?)@~/;             // <=== Note `g` removed
  var i = a.length;
  var t;
  while (i--) {
    var match = re.exec(a[i]);
    if (match && match[0] && match[1]) {
      a[i] = a[i].replace(match[0], match[1]);
    }
  }
  var res = a.join('/');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>
  My goal is to print the string: <code>a/b/c</code>. See weird <i>uncomment</i> fix in JS.
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**However**, if you leave that `g` flag on the regex, you can replace the entire contents of the `while` loop with

```
a[i] = a[i].replace(re, "$1");
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = ["a", "~@b@~", "~@c@~"]
  var re = /~@(.*?)@~/;
  var i = a.length;
  var t;
  //  Uncomment below line to see the problem change from ~@b@~ to ~@c@~
  //a.reverse();
  while (i--) {
    a[i] = a[i].replace(re, "$1");
  }
  var res = a.join('/');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>
  My goal is to print the string: <code>a/b/c</code>. See weird <i>uncomment</i> fix in JS.
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

...which also has the advantage of handling entries in the form `"~@b@~~@c@~"` (because it replaces all occurrences in the string, not just the first one).

Comment: +1. But suppose the content of the `"$1"` variable is only a variable *name* which I want to replace with its value? `a[i] = a[i].replace(re, eval("$1"));` doesn't work. Any suggestions? I can put this question in a different SO question if that would help?

Comment: @Mowzer: In that case, you'll need your loop, just without the `g` flag or with `re.lastIndex = -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the global flag from the regex to change from:

```
var re = /~@(.*?)@~/g;
```

to:

```
var re = /~@(.*?)@~/;
```

should fix this.